# Circular permutation without neighbors of 8 people, is 3 the correct answer? My answer and work included, would like feedback/alternatives

Tags: combinatorics

I stumbled a question.  A round table has 8 people, what are the total number of ways such that no one sits next to the same person again? I started this question by number people 1-8. And then set person 1 arbitrary at the head of the table.

My first attempt which ended in failure: Total number of ways this should be possible, I believe should be 7!, not 8! because the first person is fixed thus only the other 7 are rotating. SO that is the base we start with, the real answer is obviously significantly less than this. I came up with an answer of 3 but am unsure and I had to use paper to do so, I would love if there was a way to do so without paper or at least a systematic way to think about it.

I assume one arrangement: is just 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (where 8 sits next to 1)

Thus for the next choice, I initially tried to think in terms of: the number of people who can sit next to 1 is reduced from 7 to 5 because now 2 and 8 are out the window. But this leads me to a bit of rabbit hole for the next one because it's all getting flipped. I couldn't get going through this method so I thought about a different way, but I wold love it if someone could explain if and how this is viable answer.

Attempt #2 I arrived at my actual answer by looking at them in 2 pairs of 4 and then attaching neighbors so I split into a pairs: 1,2,3,4 and 5,6,7,8. And then lined them up and combined each column into a pair so 1 combined with 5, 2 combined with 6 etc. came up with a second sequence, my plan was to do this until they repeat (presumably I would have my answer)

1, 2, 3, 4 = 1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8
5, 6, 7, 8

Do it again:

1,5,2,6
3,7,4,8

And: 1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8. If we repeat we start repeating so I should be finished. Because the next sequence is:
1,3,5,7
2,4,6,8

Thus I came up with 2 alternative sequences, however is this right? Are there better more systematic/reductive ways using combinatorics to do this? I am really struggling with a good way of thinking about this question in a logical progression

Comment: I only see two solutions in your answer.  The answer has to be even because any solution can be given clockwise or counter clockwise

Comment: It certainly cannot be greater than $3$. Indeed, for each arrangement any given person sits next to $2$ different people among the $7$ others. Thus $4$ different arrangements would require at least $8$ others, for a total of $9$ people.

Comment: @JohnGriffin:  I read the problem to ask how many arrangements are possible for the second seating, not how many seatings are possible in a row without repeating neighbors.

Comment: @RossMillikan That seems to be a better interpretation.

Comment: @Ross Millikan. You are correct I misspoke, I came up with "3" sequences including 1-8 but that's not really the point of the question johnGriffin's interpretation is better, I phrased it rather poorly I apologize. I will edit my post

Comment: @JohnGriffin I don't totally understand, how did you come up with a limit of 3? Your leap to "Thus 4 different arrangements would require at least 8 others, for a total of 9" is leaving a bit confused. Are you saying if you put someone in the "main" chair as it were, because they need 2 new neighbors 4 arrangements would necessarily include 8 total? Am I understanding correctly

Comment: @JohnGriffin when I started originally I thought there would be AT least a hard limit of 5 because the next seating sequence there are only 5 people left for the neighbors for the person in Seat 1, however I thought there were other ways to arrange the people that follow thus it would 5 multiplied by some other number, and not a limit if 5. So that's why I was confused logically why it's a limit of 5, but I think I understand what you are saying

Comment: @user3002540 Sure. Consider person #1. In the first seating, they will have two neighbors. Thus, in the second seating, the two neighbors cannot be from the previous two, so we need to choose $2$ people from the remaining $7-2=5$. Similarly, on the third seating we need to choose $2$ new people from the remaining $5-2=3$. Then there only remains $1$ person that has not been seated next to person #1, so there can't be any more seatings.

Comment: @JohnGriffin, that's so brilliant, I never carried it logically from from the 5 remaining choices to narrow it down and realize there is AT LEAST a hard limit of 3. Damn, I feel very stupid. I believe this is a great way to star the problem after that I guess you can brute force to create 3 sequences and finish the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seat diner #1, $d_1$, arbitrarily. Then $d_2$ has $5$ options and $d_8$ has $4$ options. $d_3$ has $3$ or $4$ options, depending on whether $2$ and $8$ are adjacent or not, and similarly $d_4$ can have $2,3$ or $4$ options (the last if $d_3$'s new neighbours are $d_1$ and $d_8$). Generally placing the last three diners can only be done in $1$ or $2$ ways, but it is very dependent on the previous seating choices.

So expect the answer to be somewhere in the $200$-$400$ range. Not $3$.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking that originally but I believe there would serious overlap that way, I'm not sure but intuitively that felt wrong, but that's part of why I'm so confused. You may well be right, but tht's why I asked this seems slightly different than other variants I have seen on this site

Comment: I'm not sure what "serious overlap" means in this context. Basically the initial placement of $d_2$ and $d_8$ definitely has $20$ options, and I'm confident that most of those can be made to work in multiple ways.